# SailsJS - Static files can not be loaded

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I learned that the static files placed inside assets will be accessed directly in browser. But after I did this, my static files can't be accessed.

Finally, it turns out that the statics files are not compiled into the hidden folder(`.tmp/public`). It did work after I copied all the files into this hidden folder manually.

But why isn't it be done automatically? Even after I restarted my application, which has the script starting it with `sails lift`.

Comment: `sails www` helps? Also needs to add all js files into `tasks/pipeline.js` which you want to reload with this command. On my server i use my own built-in script which runs `sails www --prod` always. If some of your files wont change(like libs or socket.io), add all files into layout. 
Locally i am having no troubles with sails lift.

Comment: @mansim Thanks, Im not sure about this. I will try. But I checked my `pipeline.js` and added some patters for my `css` and `js` files, but it's still not working.

Comment: Did you find a solution, it would be ice to add it here.

Comment: @Noitidart Not working in my local environment, but it does work on my server. So I haven't figured out the root cause yet.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, please share and at me if you figure it out. I will do same for you.

Comment: @Noitidart Sure, thanks.

Comment: @Noitidart I figured it out and you can find the answer below.

Comment: Thank you @Sky for sharing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a silly mistake that the server doesn't have the permission to operate `.tmp/public` folder. As I need to debug the backend code (`NodeJS`), so I started the server with debug mode in Visual Studio Code. Which I didn't notice the permission error message as it prints lots of logs to make it invisible in current window.

It works as I started the server in command line with `sudo node app.js`.